# What tense is better to use

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

Please help me understand which tense it is better to use in the following situation: Alan meets Steve by chance. Steve doesn't recognise Alan, but Alan does recognise Steve. Alan is Steve's sister's English teacher. Alan wants to get to know Steve  and a dialogue starts:

- Hey, Steve, hello!
- Hello, do we know each other?
- I'm Alan – I ((teach) OR (am teaching)) your sister English.

What tense is it better to use (because I have found there to be different views on the situation)? It is a fact that Alan is an English teacher, so in theory I can use present simple. On the other hand it is a temporary situation (English classes will end sooner or later, everyone understands that). Although the action isn't happening at the time if speaking, the action is not still finished when they are talking. From this point of view, I should use present continuous.

Please tell me which tense would you choose. Also please explain your choice. Thanks for attention!

Comment: Those are both present tense.  "Progressive" is an aspect, not a tense.

Comment: What's wrong with "I'm your sister's English teacher."? I think "I am teaching [her] English" would suggest that it was a private arrangement. If she is in his class at school or university, "I teach..." wopuld probably be more  usual.

Comment: I'd opt for "I teach your sister English". The present continuous construction has the nuance that it's a temporary ... / perhaps even sub-optimal situation. The present simple hints at a successful conclusion.

Comment: @PeterShor that is, my question is actually similar to the question "What hair can be considered long?" ?

Comment: @KateBunting I didn’t think at all about clarifying that Alan is a private teacher who gives extra classes. I just want to subtly feel the tenses, I want to understand how native speakers think. Thank you, your comment provided a bit of clarity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that is, using this tense of the verb, I thereby deliberately emphasize that soon some action will end?

Comment: 'Soon' could be in 7 years at secondary school. But present simple sounds crisper, more professional here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it's difficult, I cannot form some kind of clear system. Tell me please, do native speakers really think about such small things when they formulate their thoughts? Or does it come naturally with some experience?

Comment: A school teacher would say "I teach your sister" (it's my job). If the sister is taking a short course, for example, Alan might say "I'm teaching your sister" (at the moment).

Comment: @KateBunting I've got it, thank you!

Comment: 'Some experience' involves a lot more than 7 years, I'm afraid. I gave up English after O-Levels, considering it too difficult, and took maths/phys/chem.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so would you recommend that I not try to understand all this in such detail, but just learn the basics of English, and then just gain experience as I use English?

Comment: There are so many exceptions to 'rules' in English that you'd go crazy not adopting a balanced approach; I've a lot to learn at 70. And naughty people keep modifying what is  accepted!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ohhh, OK, I've got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I teach your sister English." states a fact that "I am your sister's English teacher." This fact is not related to changes in the future. For example, I can say " I like apples.", it states the fact that at this moment I like apples, and it does not matter if I like apples or not in the future. Therefore, the present simple tense can be used here.